# Why don't goroutines write in parallel using WriteAt?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, file-writing

I'm experimenting a bit with reading and writing from a file.
To write to a file concurrently I created the following function:

```
func write(f *os.File, b []byte, off int64, c chan int) {
    var _, err = f.WriteAt(b, off)
    check(err)
    c <- 0
}
```

I then create a file and 100000 goroutines to perform the write operations.
They each write an array of `16384` bytes to the hard disk:

```
func main() {
    path := "E:/test"
    f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    check(err)

    size := int64(16384)
    ones := make([]byte, size)

    n := int64(100000)
    c := make(chan int, n)

    for i := int64(0); i < size; i++ {
        ones[i] = 1
    }

    // Start timing
    start := time.Now()

    for i := int64(0); i < n; i++ {
        go write(f, ones, size*i, c)
    }

    for i := int64(0); i < n; i++ {
        <-c
    }

    // Check elapsed time
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(start))

    err = f.Sync()
    check(err)
    err = f.Close()

    check(err)
}
```

In this case about 1.6 GB is written where each goroutine writes to a non-overlapping byte range. The documentation for the `io` package states that [Clients of WriteAt can execute parallel WriteAt calls on the same destination if the ranges do not overlap.](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriterAt) 
So what I expect to see, is that when I use `go write(f, ones, 0, c)`, it would take much longer since all write operations would be on the same byterange.

However after testing this my results are quite unexpected:

Using `go write(f, ones, size*i, c)` took an average of about `3s`

But using `go write(f, ones, 0, c)` only took an average of about `480ms`

Do I use the WriteAt function in the wrong way? How could i achieve concurrent writing to non-overlapping byteranges?

Comment: Just because the calls can happen in parallel, doesn't mean that writing a single file to disk isn't an inherently serial operation.

Comment: Still, isn't it weird that writing to different offsets in a file takes much longer?

Comment: No. The io system is optimized for the common use case, which is serial writes. You've also added the overhead of scheduling `100000` goroutines, and their contention on the file descriptor's lock.

Comment: I read about [FileLockEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx) which looks to me like a way of locking only a particular range of bytes in a file. Is there a way of doing something equivalent in go? Or would this not speed up the process of writing at all?

Comment: `FileLockEx ` is something entirely different. The fastest way to write a file is serially, with as few syscalls as possible. For random sparse writes across the file, `mmap` is usually how it's done in posix, but you implied that you're using windows so I'm not sure what the equivalent is.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks!